# ActionMailer not sending mail in development Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Why is this mailer not sending any mail? (Or any ideas for debugging?)

In my_app/config/environments/development.rb I have this code:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'my_app.com',
    user_name:            ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
    password:             ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

Then on my local computer in ~/.bash_profile I have this code:

```
export GMAIL_USERNAME='blah@my_app.com'
export GMAIL_PASSWORD='***'
```

When I run `$ env` in my terminal, I see that both environment variables are correctly set.

I have also restarted my rails server.

Comment: Does it work as expected in `:test` or `:file` delivery mode? That would isolate the problem to your smtp settings.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: did you change config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true, as by default this is on false, preventing mails to be sent from your development environment...

Comment: Not stupid at all @DannyVanHoof cause that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You should add

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

as by default this is on false, preventing mails to be sent from your development environment...

Comment: I recommend turning on `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` so delivery issues aren't being swallowed.

Answer (score 13):

For anyone not using smtp, switching the delivery method to sendmail helped me in addition to explicitly setting deliveries to be performed:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Comment: sendmail is quicker to configure on many servers.  Particularly useful for development mode.

Comment: i just wanted to add that for me in Rails 5, switching to :sendmail was the only thing that would work

Answer (score 9):

If you're having issues sending email from console, you have to call the deliver method on your mail.

```
MyMailer.create_email.deliver
```

Comment: that statement doesn't make sense to me. you can make that call in the console.

Comment: Simply calling your method does not actually deliver mail while in rails console. You need to call the `deliver` method on the mail object that your Mailer method returns.

Comment: my mistake, i didnt know there was a create_email method but in the latest rails (and for a while now, i assumed), `MyMailer.deliver` should be enough. and you can do that either in console or the application

Answer (score 3):

All of these answers are great, but there is another place where you can get burned, especially in the context of debugging.

In `development.rb` make sure you set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true`

If your `.deliver` method seems to be working without issue, but you never actually receive the email across the wire, your delivery method may be throwing an exception and rails is swallowing the error. This is very true if you simply have something as simple as a misconfigured credentials, or an aws access denied API error. Save ripping your hair out and make sure you have `raise_delivery_errors` turned on. It wants to tell you something but can't.

Answer (score 0):

So I've figured it out. Having the line `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp` in `config/environment.rb` overrides `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` in `config/environments/test.rb`.

So, delete that line, `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp` from `config/environment.rb` and place it in `config/environments/production.rb`. That allows you to place `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` in `config/environments/test.rb` and the version you want in `config/environments/development.rb`. I made `development.rb` `:test` as I populated my database using Faker and changed it to `:smtp` so I was sure that real emails were sent as an additional check.

Note: You must restart your server for these changes to take effect.

Another note: Heroku's current SendGrid Instructions (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid) put the SendGrid Heroku configuration code in a new `config/initializers/mail.rb` file which will likely require removing its last line and placing the desired version in each `config/environments/[production.rb, development.rb, test.rb]`