# Ruby on Rails Mailer not sending email in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a Ruby on Rails application with simple mailer which looks like this:

```
class EventMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  default from: "example.com"

  def welcome_email(event, customer)
    @event = event
    @customer = customer
    mail :subject => "Test", :to => @customer.email
  end
end
```

My action_mailer settings looks like this:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address   => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port      => 587, # ports 587 and 2525 are also supported with STARTTLS
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, # detects and uses STARTTLS
    :user_name => "my_email",
    :password  => "my_password", # SMTP password is any valid API key
    :authentication => 'login', # Mandrill supports 'plain' or 'login'
    :domain => 'yourdomain.com', # your domain to identify your server when connecting
  }
```

I have also customer registration with devise and it sends email properly. But when I try to run in my console:

```
EventMailer.welcome_email(Event.last, Customer.last).deliver
```

It does not deliver email. What can be wrong? I have no ideas...

Edit:
Rest of my config

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769589/actionmailer-not-sending-mail-in-development-rails-4

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: No theres not any errors in console...

Comment: Btw, your `default from` seems strange. An email should be put there.

Comment: OMGFG I chaged this default_from to email and it works...
I'm such a loser...

Comment: Oh, that stuff happens a lot :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 11):

Mail is not sent in development by default. To enable this you should tweak your `development.rb` like this:

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

You may also enable `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` to raise delivery errors.

**UPDATE**

It turned out to be the `default from` causing the problems as the invalid e-mail was provided.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I my configuration is proper because devise is sending mails in development.

Comment: more details on https://blog.eq8.eu/til/rails-deliver-mail-to-file.html