# Rails not sending email on development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I am developing an app on Rails 4. When user signs up using devise gem, that person can receive an email. But for cases like `successful checkout`, the user not getting any email despite there is `InvoiceMailer#checkout: processed outbound mail in 207.2ms` and `Sent mail to admin@example.com (4134.8ms)` message in console.

Following were my code:
Controller

```
def success_checkout

        token = params[:token]
        payer_id = params[:PayerID]
        @invoice = Invoice.find_by_token(token)

        request = Paypal::Express::Request.new(
            :username   => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:username],
            :password   => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:password],
            :signature  => PAYPAL_CONFIG[:signature]
        )

        payment_request = Paypal::Payment::Request.new(
            :currency_code => @invoice.currency,   
            :description   => "New payment for travel booking",
            :quantity      => 1,
            :amount        => @invoice.amount_cents.to_i / 100
        )

        response = request.checkout!(
            params[:token],
            params[:PayerID],
            payment_request
        )

        gon.is_display_currency_exchange = false
        @currency_symbol = get_all_currency_symbols[@invoice.currency]

        if response.ack == 'Success'
            @invoice.update_attributes(:payer_id => payer_id, :status => "paid")

            if @invoice.is_reward_credit
                current_user.reward_credit -= 5
                current_user.save
            end

            (1..3).each do |i|
                InvoiceMailer.checkout(@invoice, i).deliver_now
            end

            flash[:success] = "Checkouted successfully."
        else
            flash[:danger] = "There is an error while processing the payment."
        end

    end
```

InvoiceMailer

```
class InvoiceMailer < ActionMailer::Base
    default from: "MySite <support@example.com>"
    include ApplicationHelper

    def checkout(invoice,i)
        @invoice = invoice
        @currency_symbols = get_all_currency_symbols


        logger.info "{event=CHECKOUT_RECEIPT status=successful store=#{invoice.contact_detail.email}}"  
        mail(:to => invoice.contact_detail.email, :subject => "Receipt of example")



    end

end
```

My `development.rb` mailer config

```
#For mailer configs
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.com'};
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
    :port => 587,
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => 'KEY',
    :password       => 'SECRET',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

The logger message do print out in console as `{event=CHECKOUT_RECEIPT status=successful store=user@example.com}`. But receive no mail. Thanks!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionMailer not sending mail in development Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769589/actionmailer-not-sending-mail-in-development-rails-4)

Comment: @JustinWood not a duplicate, mine `config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true`.

Comment: I bet the issue is within your smtp credentials. Rails does NOT throw any error when the authentication fails. Make sure your credentials work, maybe using other client.