# Contact us gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contactus

Using the "contact us", why does it not send the mail to my desired inbox. As can be seen below, it appears to send, it just does not get delivered to my inbox.

```
    Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2016-03-09 23:01:01 +0000
Processing by ContactUs::ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "contact_us_contact"=>{"name"=>"Niall", "email"=>"John@webdev.ie", "subject"=>"Test ", "message"=>"Can anyone on stack overflow help me? "}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
  Rendered contact_us/contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.8ms)

ContactUs::ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 239.9ms

Sent mail to higginni@tcd.ie (16.5ms)
Date: Wed, 09 Mar 2016 23:01:01 +0000
From: John@webdev.ie
Reply-To: John@webdev.ie
To: higginni@tcd.ie
Message-ID: <56e0ab2d4c088_70f43ff78f97c16c80a0@Macintosh-4.local.mail>
Subject: Test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Can anyone on stack overflow help me? </p>
<p>---------------------</p>
<p>Sent by Niall from John@webdev.ie</p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contacts/new
Completed 302 Found in 285ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/contacts/new" for ::1 at 2016-03-09 23:01:01 +0000
Processing by ContactUs::ContactsController#new as HTML
  Rendered contact_us/contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 66ms (Views: 65.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I get this output in the terminal but it's not sending the email to my account. I am running it locally.

Comment: What do the server logs say? Many mail servers reject mail coming from `local.mail` by the way, so you probably want to set a real hostname at the very least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ActionMailer not sending mail in development Rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769589/actionmailer-not-sending-mail-in-development-rails-4)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker edits made, a real host name being a deployment to heroku or something of that nature?